# focal_hpc: speed up raster analysis in R

Tags: r, spatial, raster, parallel.foreach

I have a very large raster file (number of row=14810; number of columns=12392) and I would like to use the 'focal' function to average (mean function) around windows of a specific size (for instance 5 pixel X 5 pixel). I used to apply the 'focal' function in R (raster R package). However, for this large raster size the function is very slow.

I know that there is a function in 'spatial.tools' called 'focal_hpc' that can speed up the focal processing (in parallel). However, I do not know how to specifies the 'mean' function. I used the following script:

```
require(raster)
require(spatial.tools)
tahoe_highrez <- brick(system.file("external/tahoe_highrez.tif", package="spatial.tools"))

res<-focal_hpc(x=tahoe_highrez,fun=mean,window_dims=c(5,5))
```

But It gives me this error:

```
Error in (function (x, ...)  : 
  call to standardGeneric("mean") apparently not from the body of that generic function
```

Has someone experience with this package and function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm. Me too:

```
> res<-focal_hpc(x=tahoe_highrez,fun=mean,window_dims=c(5,5))
Error in (function (x, ...)  : 
  call to standardGeneric("mean") apparently not from the body of that generic function
```

but if you make a function that does the same thing:

```
> f = function(...){mean(...)}
```

it works...

```
> res<-focal_hpc(x=tahoe_highrez,fun=f,window_dims=c(5,5))
Warning messages:
1: In .local(x, ...) : min value not known, use setMinMax
2: In .local(x, ...) : max value not known, use setMinMax
3: In .local(x, ...) : min value not known, use setMinMax
> res
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 400, 400, 160000, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 5.472863e-06, 5.472863e-06  (x, y)
extent     : -119.9328, -119.9306, 39.28922, 39.29141  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : /tmp/Rtmp2WTR9g/file5f335faf907.grd 
names      : layer
```

I suspect its something to do with the way generic functions are dispatched. Make a test raster to be sure my function substitution is computing the mean of the things you want to take the mean, and read the docs for more examples of writing functions for `focal_hpc`.

Comment: I have been trying to use this function in a server for which I do not have root permissions (SLURM). I have installed the package in a local folder, and when I try to use 'focel_hpc' function in parallel (6 cores) I do get the following error: Error in e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data) : 
  worker initialization failed: there is no package called ‘spatial.tools’
Calls: system.time ... focal_hpc_focal_processing -> %dopar% -> <Anonymous>

Comment: That's a different problem - try searching for that problem and then asking a new question. You need to find out where R is looking for packages and maybe add your installation folder to it. But please make a new question if this hint doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This was also my intuition. I have posted it as a separated question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59645694/worker-initialization-failed-there-is-no-package-in-parallel-processing